# Scala Bitset toBitMask transformation

Tags: scala, bitset

Specification of `toBitMask` of `BitSet` says `Creates a bit mask for this set as a new array of longs`. But i can't understand how `toBitMask` really create a bitmask. For instance, i have the next code:

```
import scala.collection.BitSet
val nums = BitSet(6)
nums.toBitMask foreach println
```

1. It returns 64, why it return exactly 64?

An another example

```
  val nums1 = BitSet(3, 2).toBitMask
  val nums2 = BitSet(3, 2, 0).toBitMask
```

2. Why nums1 = 12 while nums2 = 13?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what's happening is that `.toBitMask` treats each number in the BitSet as saying "this bit number will be set to 1".

```
BitSet(0).toBitMask == Array(1)
BitSet(1).toBitMask == Array(2)
BitSet(2).toBitMask == Array(4)
BitSet(3).toBitMask == Array(8)
```

So if you have `BitSet(3, 2)`, you are creating a number where bits 3 and 2 (zero-indexed) are 1:

```
00001100
```

This is binary for 12. `BitSet(3,2,0)` creates

```
00001101
```

which is binary for 13.

Comment: It `BitSet(3, 2) --> 00001100` looks like`2` is ignored?

Comment: It's not ignored; the last "1100" is bit numbers 3,2,1,0

Comment: `toBitMask` doesn't seem to *actually* create a bitmask of your set. Instead it's creating something like a "BitString" where bit number `i` is set to 1 if `i` was in your BitSet. With "1101", bit numbers 0, 2, and 3 are set to 1. With "1100" bit numbers 2 and 3 are set to 1. (bit number zero is the right-most bit)

Comment: The reason it's an `Array` is so that if the largest number stored is greater than 64 (the number of bits in a `Long`), it can still set the bit in another `Long` in the array.